# Java factorial printing wrong value

Tags: java

I need help with an exercise I am doing. I am currently learning Java. I am doing a factorial exercise, whereby my application prompt a user of a number and then compute the factorial of that number and returned it to be displayed.

This is my GUI class:

```
public String factorial;
public String fieldnumber;

public String calculateFactorial() {
    fieldnumber = this.numberField.getText();
    Number number = new Number(Integer.parseInt(fieldnumber));
    System.out.print(number.toString());

    return number.toString();
}

private void calculateBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
     System.out.println( this.calculateFactorial());
}
```

This is my Number class:

```
public class Number {    
    private int number;
    int i,fact=1;

    public Number(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Integer getNumber(){
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    private Integer computeFactorial(){
        for(i=1; i<=number ;i++){    
            fact=fact*i;              
        }
      return this.fact;
    }

    public String toString() { 
        return Integer.toString(this.computeFactorial());
    }
}
```

When I print my computed factorial the true result is part of the printed garbage value. factorial of 6 is 720, but I am seeing 720518400 the first three numbers are the correct and the garbage not sure where it's coming from.

Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the for loop, you must initialize fact=1; because you call the method twice.

```
private Integer computeFactorial(){
      fact = 1;
      for(i=1; i<=number ;i++){    
        fact=fact*i;  
     }
      return this.fact;
}
```

Comment: this is working by returning the correct value but the value is still being duplicated. like factorial 6 is giving 720720

Comment: In the method calculateFactorial, you call System.out.print(number.toString()); that prints 720 and returns number.toString(); to calculateBtnActionPerformed that print the returned value (720) a second time